How to sort json data in Mule 4 Dataweave
I need to sort JSON data which can contain array as well as objects
sample data :
    {
    "results": [
        {
            "empCode": "abcd",
            "age": 33,
            "awards": [
                {
                    "year": 2024,
                    "status": [
                        "X1",
                        "FA",
                        "VE"
                    ]
                }
            ]
            
        },
        {
            "empCode": "abcd",
            "age": 33,
            "awards": [
                {
                    "year": 2024,
                    "status": [
                        "X1",
                        "FA",
                        "VE"
                    ]
                }
            ]
            
        }    
    ]
}

Using this script I am able to sort :
%dw 2.0
output application/json
  fun sortObjects(x)=
    x match {
        case o is Object -> o 
                              orderBy ((value, key) -> key)
                              mapObject (($$): sortObjects($))
        case a is Array -> a map ((item, index) -> item match { 
                              case abc1 is Object -> abc1 
                                                     orderBy ((value, key) -> key)
                                                     mapObject (($$): sortObjects($))
                              else -> $ 

                            } 
                              )
        else -> $ 
  }  
---
sortObjects(payload)

So this is sorting fine based on the keys which is fine
However I also want to sort the string array status in ascending order as well .
Presently it appears as :
 "status": [
      "X1",
      "FA",
      "VE"
    ],

I would want it to appear as:
 "status": [
      "FA",
      "VE",
      "X1"
    ],

How do I achieve this ?

Do you have heterogeneous arrays (array with elements of different datatype) as well?

no this is pretty much the way data will be present

You only need to make a small correction in your script. Basically, you are not sorting array at all in case the array is not an array of Object.
Also, when the array is array of objects, you can recursively call the same function since you already have the logic to sort objects written in the same function.
case a is Array -> if(a[0] is Object) a map sortObjects($) 
                   else (a orderBy $)

